# Hue's Spark notebook not working on cloudera quickstart vm

Tags: cloudera, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Recently i installed cloudera quickstart vm 5.8 on my windows machine on top of VMware. By default Spark UI link and Zookeeper link was not there on Hue so, i just edited the hue.ini which had,

```
app_blacklist = zookeeper, spark
```

to

```
app_blacklist =
```

After doing this i was able to download some Spark examples but the Spark UI link was still not displayed. However i was able to get the zookeeper UI link.

From the downloaded examples i selected sample notebook through which i was able to get the Spark notebook UI. It had some examples but when i run them i'm getting the following error.

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8998): Max retries exceeded with url: /sessions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdd7c5f2e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Do i need to make any changes in addition to the one i have done in hue.ini file. Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

The error was rectified after i installed livy server and ran it using the following commands in terminal;

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
$HOME/livy-server-0.2.0/bin/livy-server
```